# How to correctly apply matrix transformations on multiple models?

Tags: javascript, matrix, webgl, transformation

I am trying to accomplish an animation of a tree growing in WebGL.

In this project, I have 2/3 models that make the building block of the tree.

- Branch model
- Leaf model
- Trunk model

Now I apply various sorts of Matrix transformation in those models, like Translation, Scaling, Rotation, etc.

My question is how to efficiently organize these things in the project.

I'm not using any library, but handling everything by myself. I have gotten custom Scene, Camera functions which is working pretty well.

But what I'm stuck at is I cannot apply specific transformations to a specific  individual model.

Also,

I cannot dynamically change the camera clip space, as more and more models get loaded.

**Can anyone help me out with the basic organization of the project?**

Comment: Why don't you just look at existing projects and see how they organize things?

Comment: @gman yeah sounds good, and that was my very first step. But unfortunately, I didn't see any project which does these things(loading and transforming models in runtime, without using any library like Three.js etc. )using simple Camera/Scene function

Comment: What I meant was look inside three.js or some other framework. It's not clear how we can answer your question really. How do you want to organize things? Do you want a scenegraph? Do you want a render tree? Do you want materials? Do you want the 24 semi standard matrices? Do you want ...? This basically turns into an opinion question. Hence my suggestion to look at other examples and by examples I mean inside the frameworks themselves. SceneGL, ImpactJS, Three.js, Babylon.js etc.. Most frameworks use some kind of [scene graph](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html).

Comment: @ikis How big tree do you want? Lets say 20k leafs, 2000 branches, 100 trunk parts? Small trees might be cpu generation based, while large trees require very different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Procedural maple tree at
http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/tree/maple.htm
and notes at the bottom